# Yii : Rules Checking On Different Scenario

Tags: php, validation, yii

i want to check different validation in one controller.

i have problem is,

when user is registering first time at that time i want to do following validation

```
 array('name, email, password, location, confirm_password', 'required','on'=>'create'), 
 array('confirm_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' =>  'password','on'=>'create,fbuser'),     
 array('email','unique','on'=>'create'),
```

and if user is already registered with FB and trying to register at that time i want to do following validation (i don't want to validate email address in this case)

```
   array('name, password, location, confirm_password', 'required','on'=>'fbuser'), 
   array('confirm_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password','on'=>'create,fbuser'),
```

this is my controller method...

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
            $model=new AppUser('create');

            if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                $this->redirect('/');

            if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
            {
                    if($model->isFbUser($_POST['email'])){
                        $model->scenario = 'fbuser';
                        if($model->validate())
                            $this->redirect(array('/Appuser/fbauth','email'=> $_POST['email']));
                    }
                    else
                        $model->scenario = 'create';

                    $model->attributes=$_POST;
                    if($model->save())
                            $this->redirect('/login');
            }

            $this->render('create',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
            ));
    }
```

but its not validating properly.

can anyone help me to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be, that in the if (isFbUser) clause you do not assign the post data to the model before validating.

Your use of scenarios looks good to me.

Comment: isFbUser is my function which is returning true or false based on some conditions and its working fine if i remove all the validations.

Comment: i believe you that isFbUser is working, however if it returns true, you will be doing $model->validate() two lines after. You have not assigned post data to your model, so the model data will not validate.